# Rails self referential data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have a model named `Skill`. I want skills to have the possibilities have having `parents` and `children` skills.

What I currently have:

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: Skill
  has_many :parents, foreign_key: :child_id, class_name: Skill
end
```

However, this is not picking up on the join table that I have created for this (`skill_relations`).

How would I either specify the table that I have created, or what should the proper name of the join table so that rails can pick this relationship up automatically?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `has_many`, Rails assumes that the associated table is derivable from the symbol you've provided (e.g. the table `children` for `:children`).

If you want to have a separate "relations" table, you specify it with the `through` parameter, as in:

```
has_many :children, foreign_key: :parent_id, through: :skill_relations
has_many :parents, foreign_key: :child_id, through: :skill_relations
```

Comment: Isn't the :through parameter only applicable if I have a model for :skill_relations?

Comment: I haven't tried it without a model, so I don't know the answer to that. The only case where I know a model isn't required is in the case of `has_and_belongs_to_many`, which assumes a table of the form `a_b` where `a` and `b` are the plural form of the two tables in question, in alphabetical order.